# Converting a list of list of data.frames to a single data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, lapply

I have a `list` of `list` of `data.frames` (see `L` below).

I was wondering if it might be possible to convert `L` to my **desired output shown below** which is a single `data.frame`?

```
L <- list(A = list(Short = data.frame(d = 1:2, SD = 3:4)), 
          B = list(Short = data.frame(d = 2:3, SD = 1:2), Long1 = data.frame(d = 7:8, SD = 6:7)),
          C = list(Short = data.frame(d = 5:6, SD = 3:4), Long1 = data.frame(d = 8:9, SD = 1:2), 
               Long2 = data.frame(d = 4:5, SD = 6:7)))
```

**Desired output (a `data.frame`):**

```
d  SD id
1  3   1
2  4   1
2  1   2
3  2   2
7  6   2
8  7   2
5  3   3
6  4   3
8  1   3
9  2   3
4  6   3
5  7   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply/Map` in `base R`.  We can loop through the `list` with `lapply`, `rbind` the nested `list` elements, then create a new column with `Map` and `rbind` the outer `list` elements

```
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lapply(L, function(x) 
              do.call(rbind, x)), id = seq_along(L)))
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#   d SD id
#1  1  3  1
#2  2  4  1
#3  2  1  2
#4  3  2  2
#5  7  6  2
#6  8  7  2
#7  5  3  3
#8  6  4  3
#9  8  1  3
#10 9  2  3
#11 4  6  3
#12 5  7  3
```

---

Based on the comments, if we need to add another column from the `names` of the inner `list`

```
out1 <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lapply(L, function(dat)
   do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, dat, es.type = names(dat)))), id = seq_along(L)))
row.names(out1) <- NULL

out1
#   d SD es.type id
#1  1  3   Short  1
#2  2  4   Short  1
#3  2  1   Short  2
#4  3  2   Short  2
#5  7  6   Long1  2
#6  8  7   Long1  2
#7  5  3   Short  3
#8  6  4   Short  3
#9  8  1   Long1  3
#10 9  2   Long1  3
#11 4  6   Long2  3
#12 5  7   Long2  3
```

---

If there are `..\\d+` and want to remove

```
out1 <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lapply(L, function(dat)
   do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, dat, 
     es.type = sub("\\.*\\d+$", "", names(dat))))), id = seq_along(L)))
row.names(out1) <- NULL
out1
#   d SD es.type id
#1  1  3   Short  1
#2  2  4   Short  1
#3  2  1   Short  2
#4  3  2   Short  2
#5  7  6    Long  2
#6  8  7    Long  2
#7  5  3   Short  3
#8  6  4   Short  3
#9  8  1    Long  3
#10 9  2    Long  3
#11 4  6    Long  3
#12 5  7    Long  3
```

Comment: @rnorouzian. You can do `do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lapply(L, function(dat) do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, dat, es.type = names(dat)))), id = seq_along(L)))`

Comment: Like here `Long1` and `Long2` must be just `Long` under `es.type`.

Comment: @Reza I think you need `do.call(rbind, c(Map(...., list(make.row.names = FALSE)))`

Comment: @Reza I guess you wanted it on the outer `rbind` right, so it should be the outer most

Comment: @Reza. May be you made some typo.  What is the issue with `row.names(out1) <- NULL`

Comment: @Reza. I mentioned `c(` i.e. `do.call(rbind, c(Map(cbind, lapply(L, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)), id = seq_along(L)),list(make.row.names = FALSE)))`

Comment: @Reza `plot(table(D$time), col = g)` is very compact :=)

Comment: @Reza Try `do.call(rbind, Filter(Negate(is.null),  Map(cbind, lapply(L, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)), id = seq_along(L))))`

Comment: @Reza Yes, you are right.  I didn't test it as there was no reproducible example for the `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

We could try rbinding every list in `L` and adding a new column which would denote the list number and finally bring the entire list into one dataframe using `do.call` and `rbind`.

```
output <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(L), function(x) 
                          transform(do.call(rbind, L[[x]]), id = x)))
rownames(output) <- NULL

output
#   d SD id
#1  1  3  1
#2  2  4  1
#3  2  1  2
#4  3  2  2
#5  7  6  2
#6  8  7  2
#7  5  3  3
#8  6  4  3
#9  8  1  3
#10 9  2  3
#11 4  6  3
#12 5  7  3
```

---

It might be a bit shorter using `dplyr`'s `bind_rows` with `purrr::map` but this gives `id` variable as name of the list(`A`, `B`, `C`) instead of sequence which should not be difficult to change.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(purrr::map(L, bind_rows), .id = "id")  %>%
          mutate(id = match(id, unique(id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible approach using purrr's `flatten_dfr`:

```r
library(purrr)

transform(flatten_dfr(L), id = rep(seq_along(L), times = map(L, ~sum(lengths(.x)))))
#>    d SD id
#> 1  1  3  1
#> 2  2  4  1
#> 3  2  1  2
#> 4  3  2  2
#> 5  7  6  2
#> 6  8  7  2
#> 7  5  3  3
#> 8  6  4  3
#> 9  8  1  3
#> 10 9  2  3
#> 11 4  6  3
#> 12 5  7  3
```

NB: here I used base R's `transform` which could be replaced by dplyr's `mutate`

Answer (score 0):

`rbindlist()` is a convenience function which makes one data.table from a list of many. For this nested list it has to be applied twice recursively.

In addition, it has the `idcol` parameter which creates a column in the result showing which list item those rows came from.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(L, rbindlist, idcol = "es.type"), idcol = "id")
```

> ```
>     id es.type d SD
>  1:  A   Short 1  3
>  2:  A   Short 2  4
>  3:  B   Short 2  1
>  4:  B   Short 3  2
>  5:  B   Long1 7  6
>  6:  B   Long1 8  7
>  7:  C   Short 5  3
>  8:  C   Short 6  4
>  9:  C   Long1 8  1
> 10:  C   Long1 9  2
> 11:  C   Long2 4  6
> 12:  C   Long2 5  7
> ```

---

Now, the OP has requested that `id` is numeric and that [`Long1` and `Long2` must become `Long`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454864/converting-a-list-of-list-of-data-frames-to-a-single-data-frame-in-r/57505523#comment101385622_57455663). This can be achieved by subsequent operations on the result columns:

```
rbindlist(lapply(L, rbindlist, idcol = "es.type"), idcol = "id")[
  , id := rleid(id)][
    , es.type := sub("\\d+$", "", es.type)][]
```

> ```
>     id es.type d SD
>  1:  1   Short 1  3
>  2:  1   Short 2  4
>  3:  2   Short 2  1
>  4:  2   Short 3  2
>  5:  2    Long 7  6
>  6:  2    Long 8  7
>  7:  3   Short 5  3
>  8:  3   Short 6  4
>  9:  3    Long 8  1
> 10:  3    Long 9  2
> 11:  3    Long 4  6
> 12:  3    Long 5  7
> ```

---

In base R, we can achieve the same by

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(L, do.call, what = "rbind"))
```

which returns

> ```
>           d SD
> A.Short.1 1  3
> A.Short.2 2  4
> B.Short.1 2  1
> B.Short.2 3  2
> B.Long1.1 7  6
> B.Long1.2 8  7
> C.Short.1 5  3
> C.Short.2 6  4
> C.Long1.1 8  1
> C.Long1.2 9  2
> C.Long2.1 4  6
> C.Long2.2 5  7
> ```

`id` and `es.type` can be retrieved from parsing the row names, e.g.,

```
DF <- do.call("rbind", lapply(L, do.call, what = "rbind"))
id <- stringr::str_extract(row.names(DF), "^[^.]*")
# create sequence number (that's what data.table::rleid() does)
DF$id <- c(1L, cumsum(head(id, -1L) != tail(id, -1L)) + 1L)
DF$es.type <- stringr::str_extract(row.names(DF), "(?<=\\.)[^.0-9]*")
row.names(DF) <- NULL
DF
```

> ```
>    d SD id es.type
> 1  1  3  1   Short
> 2  2  4  1   Short
> 3  2  1  2   Short
> 4  3  2  2   Short
> 5  7  6  2    Long
> 6  8  7  2    Long
> 7  5  3  3   Short
> 8  6  4  3   Short
> 9  8  1  3    Long
> 10 9  2  3    Long
> 11 4  6  3    Long
> 12 5  7  3    Long
> ```